# Set Discord Web App to run at boot in Raspbian 10 Buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, discord, raspbian-buster

Would like to get Discord to run on boot in full screen mode.

What I am using:

- Raspberry Pi 4 8gb
- Raspbian 10 Buster
- Pi Apps(current) distribution of
- Discord WebApp(current)

What I have tried:

- rc.local
- .bash
- init.d

Not sure if I am following the directions wrong, or because it is a desktop app rather than a .py?

For reference I have tried following these instructions inserting:

`usr/shr/applications/electron-dsicord-webapp.desktop`

where it lists `sample.py`

https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Anyway, is it possible to script it to run on boot; is it also possible to make it go auto full screen?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the file `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` and parent directories if not already there:

```
$ mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE
$ touch /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

2. Create a script:

```
$ sudo nano /bin/fullscreendiscord
```

and then add the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# open Discord in the background
discord &
# find Discord and then execute ctrl+shift+F (fullscreen on Discord)
sleep 6 ; xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Discord" windowactivate key ctrl+shift+F
```

3. Add the script to the autostart file:

```
$ echo '@fullscreendiscord' >> /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

4. Reboot to apply the changes

```
$ sudo reboot
```

### NOTE:

#### I am expecting that you have Discord installed as a desktop application

If you want to run discord on Firefox, replace /bin/fullscreendiscord with

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# open Firefox with Discord open in the background
firefox https://discord.com/app &
# find Firefox and then execute F11
sleep 1 ; xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11
```

Comment: I am using the Pi-Apps distribution of Discord (Web App).

After following you instruction (which make complete sense) it did not work.  I believe this is due to some weird way in which Pi-Apps installs Discord, as I cannot find the actual install only .desktop files.

Comment: Can you launch Discord with by running `discord` in a terminal?
You could also try the Firefox version

Comment: You can also try running `/usr/share/discord-linux-armv7l/discord` in a terminal. If this one works you can try replacing `discord &` with `/usr/share/discord-linux-armv7l/discord &` in /bin/fullscreendiscord

Comment: You should also make sure you have the `xdotool` apt package installed if it does not go to fullscreen.

Comment: So I have confirmed xdotool is installed.  I also know that if I input <code>exec electron-discord-webapp</code> it will run, but if I put that before the & in the bash script I get nothing.  Any ideas?  If it helps the path for the app is /usr/share/application/electron-discord-webapp (<I have already tried this as well)

Comment: So you can run it with `/usr/share/application/electron-discord-webapp`?

Comment: Can you comment the output of `command -v electron-discord-webapp`

Comment: That outputs `/usr/bin/electron-discord-webapp`

Comment: Haven't solved it yet but wanted to get you the rep reward

Comment: Have you tried the Firefox script? You can replace `firefox` with `chromium` if you want

Comment: This is directly C&P from my fullscreendiscord script
`!/bin/bash

# open Discord in the Background
firefox https://discord.com/app &
#find Discord and then execture fn+F11(fullscreen
sleep 1 ; xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowkeyactivate Fn+F11`

Comment: You shouldn't need the Fn "key" on there. After all it's just virtually sending keypresses to certain X clients